# Error when using JAXB to create JAva classes from XSD

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb, schema

I have an XSD that describes a client's  web service API.  I'm using JAXB but when it parses the XSD file it throws errors.  I open same XSD in Eclipse and it can't recognize those data types, so same problem in Eclipse.
Here is the XSD file:https://api-build.vitalware.com/metadata?xsd=1

```
xjc -d src -p file.xsd

parsing a schema...
[ERROR] src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'q1:DateTimeOffset' to a(n) 'type d
efinition' component.
  line 9 of file:/C:/workspace/lab/file.xsd

[ERROR] src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'q2:ArrayOfint' to a(n) 'type defin
ition' component.
  line 44 of file:/C:/workspace/lab/file.xsd

[ERROR] src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'q4:ResponseStatus' to a(n) 'type d
efinition' component.
  line 153 of file:/C:/workspace/lab/file.xsd
```

They seem to be Microsoft related data types which Java doesn't recognize.  If this is true, is there another tool out there that knows how to link XSD's between Microsoft and Java?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There should be a namespace that defines those datatypes. That namespace should have its own XSD. Please post the namespace declaration part of your XSD file.

Comment: What you want to achieve? If you are trying to generate client and eclipse don't have any issue then continue to use eclipse to generate client.

Comment: Here is the XSD file: https://api-build.vitalware.com/metadata?xsd=1

Comment: @BoristheSpider yep you were right.  Separate XSD files for those data types.  Didn't look hard enough on their documentation. Thanks!!!